# "There was an internal API error." while running an app on any iPhone/iPod-touch device

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am in the process of submitting an iPhone app to the App Store. While making the final touches to the app I was in the process of compiling and running the app on my iPhone when I got this message:

> There was an internal API error.

The console had this to say:

```
25/08/2010 10:10:54 Xcode[3556] Failed willExecute: Error Domain=com.apple.platform.iphoneos Code=0 UserInfo=0x2011adec0 "There was an internal API error." -- {
    NSLocalizedDescription = "There was an internal API error.";
    NSLocalizedFailureReason = "";
    NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "";
}
```

The problem is specific to this project, others projects don't suffer the same problem. The same problem exhibits when moved to another machine, or another mobile device is swapped in.

I should be most grateful for any hints or ideas on the subject.

Comment: Would this happen right at the beginning or when the app has run for some time already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha! Thank heavens for subversion. Through comparison with a working version I found out that an offending 'UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities' in my info.plist was at fault. A little figure digging showed it had to be an Array or Dictionary, and not a string as was my case. Setting it thusly ...

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>still-camera</string>
</array>
```

.. solved the problem.

@Toastor, this happened during the deployment process, even before the app went down the wire to the device.

Comment: This was my problem as well, in my case I had deleted the "armv7" string in that array, after I added that it worked fine.

Comment: Yah! Solved problem to me too that I move <string> "armv7" from <array> to root <dict> everything goes fine.

Comment: This didn't solve my problem. For me, this error keeps popping up only on one device, leading to thinking that there is a problem with that device only, the others work fine. So, no problems in build settings or whatsoever.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem on Xcode 4.5 beta 4 when I've tried to run an app which was already installed on my iOS device. You could try to remove your app from device and make sure you are using Developer profile for signing.

Comment: Same here. Are we doing something wrong or is it a problem with the beta?

Comment: After looking further I think it's iOS 6, not xCode. I found that I can install multiples times on an iOS 5.1 device from xCode 4.5, but doing so on my iOS 6 device causes the internal server error.

Comment: Same here. Updated Xcode preview to debug on a device with the latest-beta iOS 6. Deleting the app worked.

Answer (score 2):

my problem was using a distribution profile, forgot to change back to a developer profile and that was what caused the internal api error. hope it helps someone

Answer (score 2):

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/11634

States that you need to change project name to an english name

Comment: Provide brief answer here.

Comment: More information: my project name was in Chinese and had been working fine for years.  But apparently recent versions of Xcode changed something (I'm using 7.1.1).  Now a project name with Chinese characters won't install on a phone, although it runs fine in the emulator.  I had to change the project name to something that contained only Roman letters.  Even one Chinese character caused it to fail.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. My case was an iPhone that was used for the first time on the laptop. I fixed it by opening the project in XCode with the iPhone plugged in. Xcode will then say "Processing symbol files". When finished, deploying on iPhone worked from within the QT Creator.

Comment: same thing here, I had never synced the device with iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and it worked when I removed the app from my phone and Built and Run again. I'm guessing you might have tested a build from a different branch and then tried to switch back to yours.

Answer (score 1):

I deal with same problem, but because of manually deleting "Application/Myapp" folder.
I copied back the files and uninstall it. Then I tried to run it using Xcode. Now every things is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well - the problem turned out to be in the entitlements. I had get-task-allow set to NO instead of to YES. Once this was set properly everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

1.Check your  project's  Info.plis document  code (not table list--open as source
 code  ).There may be configuration error.

2.I solve the problem by this way :  Create a new project , Compare the Info.plis code, and fix the old one .

that  works for me ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the device from Xcode.

General -> Signing -> Register.

Answer (score 0):

I had it when removing a day extension / widget and forgetting to remove the Embed App Extensions item where the extesion is listed as plug-in

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I tried running my project from a different Mac than it was created.

My issue was in the info.plist file. We were only able to figure it out after recreating the project from scratch and adding one file at a time and trying to debug it.

Replaced the following the info file:

1. CFBundleDevelopmentRegion Language en name with $(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)
2. CFBundleExecutable Name with $(EXECUTABLE_NAME)
3. CFBundleName  Name with placeholder $(PRODUCT_NAME)

Remove

CFBundleSignature

[Screenshot of Diff file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBWb3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I turned off my iPhone and when I turned it back on, it worked!

After I tried everything, I noticed that it worked on another iPhone, so I tried everything on the device where it did not work. So unfortunate that this unexpected trick had to be the solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same error when XCode+MonkeyDev to debug YouTube ipa.

Finally fixed by:

1. try more
2. and `XCode` -> **Clean Build Folder**

Answer (score -1):

As explained in another post with the same problem, it sounds crazy but you can also not use the Beta version of Xcode 4. However, you must keep it in your left hand to authorize your iPhone to compile with the non Beta version (don't ask me why, it works).

If you run your app with Xcode 4.5 preview & iOS 6 Beta 4, the second time you run your app on the device, you'll get the internal API error.

In theory, you cannot use Xcode 4.4 to compile on your iOS6 Beta 4 iPhone.

But...

It seems that, if you launch Xcode 4.5 Preview, connect your iPhone (so it is recognized), run the application on it (even if you get the error), quit Xcode 4.5, launch Xcode 4.4 and .. tadaaaa... your iPhone is now recognized as an authorized device to compile on...

And of course, Xcode 4.4 doesn't generate the API error...