# App installation failed in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7

when I try to debug in iOS 7 then it gives me error as **App installation failed. There was an internal API error.**

But it works fine with iOS 8 device.

[image]

**Help me to solve this**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564392/there-was-an-internal-api-error-while-running-an-app-on-any-iphone-ipod-touch

Comment: try to remove the app from device or  simulator. then try again.

Comment: @hasan83 , I already did this but not solve my problem

Comment: Check the Console logs, try another device and another app, try simulator, in other words help us to help you.

Comment: If you haven't done so, you might want to nuke `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

Comment: @A-Live, thanks for answer  but not solved my problem

Comment: @AdrianB,  thanks for answer  but not solved my problem

Comment: @user2526811 Thanks for the comment, but it doesn't help me to help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please check your product name under build settings. Is should not contain any special character. I have seen it failing if it contains any.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: In my case it was cyrillic symbols - moved to english and app had installed.

Answer (score 1):

Follow those steps:

1. Delete the app from the device/iOS Simulator
2. Restart the device/iOS Simulator
3. Close Xcode
4. When the device is ready re-open the Xcode project
5. Press `⌘ + K` to clean-up the project's caches
6. Press `⌘ + R` to run the app on the Device/iOS Simulator

If those steps doesn't work try to restart you Mac and to repeat those steps, also check the `bundle identifier` of your Xcode project