# Run Detached App on iOS Device

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I’m new to this, so please bear with me.

After I detach an app, I’d like to run it on an iOS device. I don’t intend to put it in the App Store or sell it. I’m just building it to teach myself Expo/React Native. I’d rather not use TestFlight or run it through the ExpoClient, since I’m building a standalone app.

When I ran:

```
exp build:iOS --clear-credentials
```

I provided my:

1. Apple Push Service P12 file
2. iOS Production Mobile Provisioning Profile
3. iOS Production P12 file

Expo compiles and creates a huge IPA, which I downloaded. I read that it’ll slice the app when installing on iPad or iPhone. When I tried to drag it into the apps section of Xcode’s Devices & Simulators window for my iPhone, it gives me the following message:

```
iPhone is busy: Installing to iPhone | Performing install actions.
```

and then states:

```
App installation failed. There was an internal API error.
```

The certs/p12s are valid, un-expired, and un-revoked. I use “Production” for all three. Is this correct or should I be using development? Is there another reason why it should fail to install on the device?

This is the information I see in Console for the Device when I search for the app processes:

```
default 17:58:25.067999 -0400   mobile_installation_proxy   (null):5:1:1:1:Beginning installation for file:///var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/myapp.ipa/ with options {
    AllowInstallLocalProvisioned = 1;
    IsUserInitiated = 1;
    PackageType = Customer;
}
default 17:58:25.074385 -0400   lsd (null):5:1:1:1:Ininstall file:///var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/myapp.ipa/ with options {
    AllowInstallLocalProvisioned = 1;
    IsUserInitiated = 1;
    PackageType = Customer;
}
default 17:58:25.076205 -0400   lsd (null):5:1:1:1:Ininstall file:///var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/install.ipa/ with options {
    AllowInstallLocalProvisioned = 1;
    IsUserInitiated = 1;
    PackageType = Customer;
}
default 17:58:25.098446 -0400   installd    0x16f65f000 -[MIClientConnection _doInstallationForURL:withOptions:completion:]: Install of "/var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/myapp.ipa" type Customer (LSInstallType = (null)) requested by lsd (pid 84)
default 17:58:25.236942 -0400   assertiond  Request to create termination assertion <BKSTerminationAssertionCreateEvent: 0x147d56050; Identifier: 12222-1C39A932-E653-4E9F-BBB7-6B6034CDF2B4; Name: FBSApplicationTerminationAssertion; Target BundleID: com.mycompany.myapp; Efficacy: Unconditional> from client <BKClientHandle: 0x147d227a0; installd:12222; connections: 1>
default 17:58:25.243369 -0400   installd    Acquired termination assertion for event <BKSTerminationAssertionCreateEvent: 0x100c20de0; Identifier: 12222-1C39A932-E653-4E9F-BBB7-6B6034CDF2B4; Name: FBSApplicationTerminationAssertion; Target BundleID: com.mycompany.myapp; Efficacy: Unconditional>
default 17:58:25.257927 -0400   installd    0x16f65f000 -[MIInstaller performInstallationWithError:]: Installing <MIInstallableBundle ID=com.mycompany.myapp; Version=1, ShortVersion=1.0.0>
default 17:58:25.259713 -0400   installd    com.mycompany.myapp:7:5:1:1:Start : Install (New)
default 17:58:42.115349 -0400   installd    com.mycompany.myapp:7:5:2:0:Fail (End) : Install (New)
default 17:58:42.119070 -0400   lsd (null):5:1:2:0:MobileInstallation returned nil for file:///var/mobile/Media/PublicStaging/myapp.ipa/
```

Comment: Any of the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564392/there-was-an-internal-api-error-while-running-an-app-on-any-iphone-ipod-touch) help you?

Comment: Have you tried to run/install it via xcode?  I use an 'ejected' project and didn't bother w/ the expo.  It doesn't take much work to manage the native projects and libraries.

Comment: Thanks @RobelRobelLingstuyl. I ran 'exp detach' and then opened the xcworkspace in xcode. When I tried to run it on my device, I got the following error: Unable to read ExpoKit version from Podfile.lock. Make sure your project depends on ExpoKit. (TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null)
[14:26:14] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1

Comment: @BenCoffin you'll need to keep googling solutions until you get there.  Your error may be handled in this thread.  Check it out.  https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/issues/436

Comment: Thank you @RobelRobelLingstuyl. I deleted the "ios" and "android" directories and re-ran "exp detach" and it seems to have correctly created the podfile.